# mvc: filter table by multiple checkboxes

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

I have a table and `company_type` is one of its columns. Let's say cells look like this:
[image]

I want to filter this table by multiple checkboxes and they have a,b,c... values.

```
 #else if 
        {
            if (checkedBoxes.Length == 1)
            {
                var deneme = from check in _context.Companies where check.company_type.Contains(checkedBoxes[0]) select new Joincco { Companies = check };
            }
            else if (checkedBoxes.Length == 2)
            {
                var deneme = from check in _context.Companies where check.company_type.Contains(checkedBoxes[0]) || check.company_type.Contains(checkedBoxes[1]) select new Joincco { Companies = check };
            }
            else if (checkedBoxes.Length == 3)
            {
                var deneme = from check in _context.Companies where check.company_type.Contains(checkedBoxes[0]) || check.company_type.Contains(checkedBoxes[1]) || check.company_type.Contains(checkedBoxes[2]) select new Joincco { Companies = check };
            }
```

This code works but is there an easier way?

Comment: If you want to have your code reviewed, there's special community for Code Reviews. Here [https://codereview.stackexchange.com] You can post you code there.